# Why NaHCO3 added to the water used (Ion Chromatography Suppression)

Tags: chromatography

I'm studying HPLC detection techniques and stuck on the conductometric suppression technique. It is describing how buffer ions (in my case $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{HCO3-}$) are being either adsorbed ($\ce{Na+}$) or protonated ($\ce{H2CO3}$) which makes them electrolytically inactive and leaves just water in the column.

Great! I understand that background conductivity is a problem. What I do not get is why was $\ce{NaHCO3}$ added to the water in the first place?

Comment: Are buffers used to dissolve the sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ion chromatography usually means chromatography where aqueous (and usually inorganic) ions are the analytes.  They are separated from each other by the use of [ion exchange resins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion-exchange_resin).

If your analytes are anions, then they will be separated on an anion exchange resin.  These resins have a crosslinked organic polymer that contains permanent positive charges.  The negative charges that neutralize these resin-bound positive charges come from aqueous solution.  Different aqueous anions will have slightly different propensities to bind to and temporarily neutralize the solid-phase cations.

If you don't use an anion-containing eluent such as bicarbonate or hydroxide, the analytes that you would like to eventually detect through conductometric detection will permanently stick there!  So adding e.g. $\ce{NaHCO3}$ as an eluent will force them off of the column and ensure that your analytes eventually flow to the detector.

A decent diagram of the process is [found in this PDF from Thermo (formerly Dionex)](http://www.thermoscientific.com/content/dam/tfs/ATG/CMD/CMD%20Documents/Product%20Manuals%20&%20Specifications/Chromatography/Ion%20Chromatography/IC%20and%20RFIC%20Accessories/4270-DS-Eluent-Suppressors-23Nov10-LPN1290-10.pdf). $%edit$